# Install Windows 8 on Inspiron 7520

Tags: windows-8

I have a Dell Inspiron n7520 that came with Windows 8 Single Language pre-installed. I also have a copy of Windows 8 Pro x64. If I were to wipe the hard drive and install Windows 8 Pro, will it create any trouble due to UEFI?

I know I will have to use legacy boot rather than UEFI boot. However, when I enable legacy boot the system refuses to boot. Can legacy boot be used with a fresh install?

Comment: Why do you want to use Windows 8 Pro? The Windows 8 Pro license you have is an OEM license or an upgrade? Is there a COA sticker on your computer with Product Key?

Comment: @dimitrij: Win8 PCs do not have COA stickers any more.

Comment: You can first try "Add features to Windows 8" and entering your Pro key to see if an in-place upgrade will work, thus retaining all your apps and settings. (Obviously you can't use this if you're going from 32 to 64-bit.) Also, why shouldn't UEFI boot work for Win8 Pro?

Comment: "Add features to Windows 8" will work only if you have **Windows 8 Pro Pack**.

Comment: @dimitrij: I've personally never tried using a Win8 Pro key in Win8's Core's "Add features", but are you *sure* it will not work? I hope the OP can try and confirm either way.

Comment: I'm 100% sure. It won't work.